# PHP Images into Bootstrap Thumbnails won't go inline

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have got a relatively simple PHP connection script to a table in my database. In this table I have a link path to my image files. I call the images using a statement like this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

and then call the image into the thumbnail with bootstrap like this:

```
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="<? echo $rows['image']; ?>" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3><? echo $rows['name']; ?></h3>
        <p><? echo $rows['description']; ?></p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Open Project</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<?php
}

mysql_close();

?>
```

The pictures are correctly placed in a thumbnail, however the thumbnails are placed on a new row when it goes to the next record in the database. It should however have 3 thumbnails(3 database records) before going on to the next row.

Does anyone know how to fix this so I can have 3 thumbnails in a row?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the .row class:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4">
       ...
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the correct answer... this is the code that got three thumbnails inline before moving onto the next row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4">
        <?php while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="<? echo $rows['image']; ?>" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="caption">
                 <h3><? echo $rows['name']; ?></h3>
                <p>
                    <? echo $rows[ 'description']; ?>
                </p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Open Project</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <?php } mysql_close(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and add

```
.img-responsive{display:inline-block;}
```

to your css.
this should do it.

Comment: Thanks, Nearly worked. It put the next thumbnail inside the last but they still aren't going inline.

Comment: can you please post your css as well.

Comment: The only CSS that is being used is the one downloaded of the Bootstrap website... I can copy the relevant parts in?

Comment: i have edited my answer. add `.img-responsive{display:inline-block;}` to your css

Comment: the second picture went into the centre of the page but the next thumbnail is still underneath the first but is now taking up the whole width.